# How can I print a two-dimensional array in Perl?

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional array. When I print/dump this I get the following

My two-dimensional array:

```
push (@matrix, \@a1Comparea2);
push (@matrix, \@a3Comparea4);
```

a1Comparea2 should be the first row of the array. a3Comparea4 should be the second row of the array.

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '1 6',
            '2 7',
            '3 8',
            '4 9',
            '5 10'
          ],
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0],
          [
            '7 12',
            '8 13',
            '9 14',
            '10 15',
            '11 16'
          ],
          $VAR1->[5],
          $VAR1->[5],
          $VAR1->[5],
          $VAR1->[5]
        ];
```

When I try to print this with the following code:

```
for (my $j= 0; $j < $rows; $j++)
{
    for (my $k= 0; $k < @a1; $k++)
    {
        print "Row:$j Col:$k = $matrix[$j][$k]\n";
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Row:0 Col:0 = 1 6
Row:0 Col:1 = 2 7
Row:0 Col:2 = 3 8
Row:0 Col:3 = 4 9
Row:0 Col:4 = 5 10
Row:1 Col:0 = 1 6
Row:1 Col:1 = 2 7
Row:1 Col:2 = 3 8
Row:1 Col:3 = 4 9
Row:1 Col:4 = 5 10
```

As you can see, the data is duplicated.

Comment: The elements in the matrix that reads "$VAR->[0]" and $VAR->[5] is Data::Dumper's way of saying there are multiple copies of the same thing in your data structure. If you post more initialiazing code it might help. How is a1Comparea2 defined?

Comment: so I did some digging around. My matrix is being formed by pusshing array references into it.  Data is duplicated if arrays are pushed sequentially in a loop. but if i declare @matrix = (\@array1, \@array2) then everything is fine. know why that might be?

Comment: @ Rob: post the code that creates the array. Then someone should be able to help you. You should also look at two tutorials in Perl's internal documentation: `perldoc perllol` and `perldoc perldsc`. They are online as well: http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is you array correctly defined? 
You should use an `@` for an array and a `$` for a scalar... 
Check this [article for a quick reference](http://kbrin.a-bldg.louisville.edu/%7Erouchka/PERL/Week2.htm).

---

That article gives this simple example.

```
@matrix = (
        [3, 4, 10],
        [2, 7, 12],
        [0, 3, 4],
        [6, 5, 9],
      );
```

This creates an array with four rows and three columns.  To print the elements of the array, type:

```
for($row = 0; $row < 4; $row++) {
    for($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++) {
        print "$matrix[$row][$col] ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: I think as the dump shows, my matrix is defined correctly.  I've updated the question to show how my matrix is defined.

Comment: You've left something out.  You add two array refs, but your dump clearly shows more than that.

Comment: @Bill, I presume you are addressing `rob` who wrote the question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you used the code you showed above?

Maybe you used something like:

```
for (my $j=0; $j < $rows; $j++)
{
    for (my $k=0; $k < @a1; $k++)
    {
        print "Row:$j Col:$k = $matrix[$not_j][$k]\n";
    }
}
```

`$not_j` would evaluate always to 0, producing your output.