# Why isn't the two dimensional array in Perl printing correctly?

Tags: perl, arrays, data-structures

Handling two dimensional arrays in Perl is giving me a headache. Anyway, the following is my question:

I have a loop which pushes an array, say @twoOneArray, into another array, say @twoDimArray, and then is reset before the next iteration of loop begins and then again is pushed into @twoDimArray with new set of values. When I print this @twoDimArray using either:

```
print Dumper \@twoDimArray;
```

it gives output

*OUTPUT*

```
$VAR1 = [

      [

        'BB',

        'AA',

        'AA'
       ],
       $VAR1->[0],
       $VAR1->[0],
       $VAR1->[0]
     ];
```

or using loops

```
for (my $i=0; $i<4; $i++){
    for (my $j=0; $j<4; $j++){
         print "$twoDimArray[$i][$j] \n";
    }
}
```

the data gets duplicated.

*OUTPUT*

Row=0   BB AA AA

Row=1   BB AA AA

Row=2   BB AA AA

Row=3   BB AA AA

and so on....

I cant figure out why the both the output ways are going wrong. If I print @twoDimArray everytime (before moving to next iteration of loop, i.e. after using push function) @twoOneArray is inserted, then the values seem to be fine and not repeat themselves, but printing it in a single go seems to give the above error. Similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112988/how-can-i-print-a-two-dimensional-array-in-perl) but I am not sure if it makes sense to me. Any suggestions?

Code to build 2D array:

```
for ($k = 1; $k <= $counter; $k++){
        @twoOneArray = (); #reset it when loop starts again
        for ($j = 0; $j <= $colsInArray; $j++){
        #do stuff to create @twoOneDim
        }
        push @twoDimArray, \@twoOneArray;
        #if I print @twoDimArray if prints fine, with the exact values intact
}

print Dumper \@twoDimArray; #if I print it here it messes up
print "\n";
```

Comment: Always `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the beginning of all Perl programs.

Comment: @brad: I do. The above code is a tiny part of the actual code. so thats why did not write it here.

Comment: See this section of `perldoc perldsc`, the part where he describes "taking a reference to the same memory location repeatedly": http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#COMMON-MISTAKES The whole tutorial is very good, as is `perldoc perllol`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The output of Data::Dumper tells me that your problem is not printing the array. Data::Dumper doesn't ever lie (or only rarely).

Please show us the code you used to build the array. I'm sure that error is in that code somewhere.

UPDATE:

Now that you added the code that builds up the array, I see that you've fallen into an evil trap: You are adding the reference to @twoOneArray to your "outer" array. But the reference will always be the same each time through your loop. Change your code like this:

```
for ($k = 1; $k <= $counter; $k++){
        my @twoOneArray; # REALLY reset it when loop starts again
        for ($j = 0; $j <= $colsInArray; $j++){
            #do stuff to create @twoOneDim
        }
        push @twoDimArray, \@twoOneArray;
}
```

.. and it should work.

Comment: @Manni: I could have never thought of that error. Thanks a ton for highlighting it. I had been de-bugging this forever now. You helped me a lot and made my day! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

You've done something like this:

```
@a = (1, 2, 3);
push @b, \@a;

@a = (2, 3, 4);
push @b, \@a;

# ...
```

The problem is that you're pushing on `@b` a *reference* to `@a`. All the references point to the same `@a`. `Data::Dumper` is telling you that with its `$VAR->[0]` thing.

You need to do something like:

```
$a = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
push @b, $a;

$a = [ 2, 3, 4] ;
push @b, $a;

# ....
```

This way, the `[ ... ]` arrayref syntax will make a new referenced array each time.

I suggest a careful reading of perlreftut and perlref.

**edit:** I see you've posted your code, and yep, you're doing my example broken code. Change to using `[ ... ]` syntax and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has been answered adequately by others. I would add that the output from `Data::Dumper` is useful in spotting such problems: the `[1]` element of your array is dumped as `$VAR1->[0]` -- in other words, it is a reference to the same underlying data values stored in the `[0]` element.

Answer (score -3):

If you want an array of arrays, you should be pushing array references, e.g.

```
my @a = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8);
my @b = qw(a b c d e f g h);
my @aOfa;

push(@aOfa, \@a);
push(@aOfa, \@b);
```

Comment: The OP is pushing array references, look at the Data::Dumper output.