# Printing a two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, perl

I've tried searching for this, but I'm not sure what this condition is called.

```
my @tgs = (
    ['article series', 'sed & awk', 'troubleshooting', 'vim', 'bash'],
    ['ebooks', 'linux 101', 'vim 101', 'nagios core', 'bash 101' ]
);

print $_ foreach @tgs;
```

results in:

```
ARRAY(0x1fedcb8)ARRAY(0x200fe80)
```

What does this mean? Why is this happening, and to what does `0x1fedcb8` and `0x200fe80` refer? I understand this is most likely a commonly asked question, but please bear with me.

Comment: You have two arrays of arrays. Each of the two items in your array are arrays. What did you expect to print?

Comment: @mpapec, The optimal answer isn't present in the dup, and it isn't appropriate to post [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112988/how-can-i-print-a-two-dimensional-array-in-perl) (because while the subject of the other question asks about print a 2d array, the question itself is wildly different). I'm going to reopen it. I'd rather have other questions marked duplicates of this one as it is clear and precise. If such a question already exists, feel free to mark as dup again.

Comment: Changing `$_` in your code to `"@{$_}\n"` would print it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array that contains two references to other arrays. You are getting garbage because you are printing the references rather than the content of the arrays referenced by those references. (The hex numbers are the memory addresses at which the referenced arrays are located.)

You can print out this "two-dimensional" array using

```
for my $row (@tgs) {
   print(join(' ', @$row), "\n");
}
```

Docs: [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

Comment: Where in the code is this referencing happening? To me, it looks like it's just declaring an Array variable, and then looping through each element in @tgs and printing it. Where are the 2 other arrays?

Comment: @sbnation the text between the `[]` (these brackets anonymous array constructors) `['article series', 'sed & awk', 'troubleshooting', 'vim', 'bash']` is an array and each entire `[]` is ***itself*** an array element in `@tgs`.  See the [Perl Datastructures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for more information.

Comment: @G.Cito yet `print @$_, "\n" foreach ( @tgs );` prints what I was expecting(all of the elements, all that was done was adding a newline and encasing @tgs in parenthesis.

Comment: @sbnation, Re "Where in the code is this referencing happening?" `[ ... ]` is basically short for `do { my @anon = ( ... ) \@anon }`. It creates an array and a reference to it, and returns the reference.

Comment: @sbnation, Yeah, you can use `@$row` instead of `join(' ', @$row)`, but it won't be readable.